# merge a string column to a set of list using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this :

```
id     fruits
01     Apple, Apricot
02     Apple, Banana, Clementine, Pear
03     Orange, Pineapple, Pear
```

How can i get a list of fruits like this by deleting duplicates?

```
['Apple','Apricot','Banana','Clementine','Orange','Pear','Pineapple']
```

Comment: There are all one word tags?

Comment: sorry i dont get your question.

Comment: I think if same friuts has 2 words like `Broad bean` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
set(', '.join(df['fruits']).split(', '))
```

Output:

```
set(['Apple', 'Apricot', 'Pear', 'Pineapple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Clementine'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get an error: TypeError: sequence item 8: expected str instance, float found. Do you know why?

Comment: I think it's because of mixed data type. try to covert df['fruits']=df['fruits'].astype(str)

Comment: @MohamedThasinah - better is `set(', '.join(df['fruits']).split(', '))`

Comment: @jezrael - you are right updated to the answer, Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 5):

You can flatten `list`s created by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), convert to `set`s for unique and last to `list`s:

```
a = list(set([item for sublist in df['fruits'].str.split(', ') for item in sublist]))
print (a)
['Pineapple', 'Clementine', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Apricot', 'Orange', 'Pear']
```

Or:

```
a = df['fruits'].str.split(', ', expand=True).stack().drop_duplicates().tolist()
print (a)
['Apple', 'Apricot', 'Banana', 'Clementine', 'Pear', 'Orange', 'Pineapple']
```

Thanks @kabanus for alternative:

```
a = list(set(sum(df['fruits'].str.split(', '),[])))
```

Comment: I would use `set(sum(df['fruits'].str.split(', '),[]))` for the first option, or better yet `set(df['fruits'].str.split(', ').sum())`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got an error while using your first solution. TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable. The second one works perfectly.

Comment: @ahbon - super, glad can help!

Comment: @kabanus, i tested the performance of the different solutions provided, and yours (kabanus:1) was the fastest as well as the most concise. (kabanus:2) & (jezrael:1) also had similar timings. Very Nice! Someone told me string manipulation is often faster in plain python than in pandas, and it seems to hold true here.

Comment: @ahbon, not sure why my answer was accepted, as this one suggests a superior technique (based on brevity & performance)

Answer (score 3):

using `str.extractall` & `drop_duplicates`

```
df.fruits.str.extractall(r'(\w+)').drop_duplicates()[0].tolist()
```

outputs:

```
['Apple', 'Apricot', 'Banana', 'Clementine', 'Pear', 'Orange', 'Pineapple']
```